# Nginx Reverse proxy with docker-compose error worker_connections are not enough

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, debian, nginx-reverse-proxy

Based on this toturial i create a website with php docker compose on debian vps.
https://devops.tutorials24x7.com/blog/containerize-wordpress-with-nginx-php-mysql-and-phpmyadmin-using-docker-containers

Since port 80 is used by an other container. i tryed to use reverse proxy to redirect the connection from [www.mydomaine.com](http://www.mydomaine.com)  to http://myip:8080 with proxy_pass by the redirection is rejected by the server.
here is my default.conf file.
FYI: i can access http://myip:8080

```
upstream php {
        server unix:/tmp/php-cgi.socket;
        #php server
        server myadress:8081;
}
server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php;

        root /var/www/html;

        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;


        server_name mydomaine.com  www.mydomaine.com ;

        location = /favicon.ico {
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
                allow all;
                log_not_found off;
                access_log off;
        }

        location / {
                # This is cool because no php is touched for static content.
                # include the "?$args" part so non-default permalinks doesn't break when using query string
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                #redirect connection reverse-proxy : code commented
                #proxy_pass http://myip:8080;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                #NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
                fastcgi_pass php;
                #The following parameter can be also included in fastcgi_params file
                fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
                expires max;
                
}
```

log trace

```
2024/02/19 19:48:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2024/02/19 19:48:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
2024/02/19 19:48:41 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2024/02/19 19:48:48 [warn] 29#29: 1024 worker_connections are not enough, reusing connections
2024/02/19 19:48:48 [alert] 29#29: 1024 worker_connections are not enough
2024/02/19 19:48:48 [error] 30#30: *2024 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: mydomaine.com, request: "GET / H$
```

Thanks for help